Adding custom information in HTML report using "JEST_HTML_REPORTERS_CUSTOM_INFOS"
I am trying to include my additional information in the HTML report using JEST_HTML_REPORTERS_CUSTOM_INFOS variable. Here is my jest setup
// jest.config.json 
{
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": ["<rootDir>/dist/"],
    "verbose": true,
    "globalSetup": "./globalSetup.ts",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/utils/setup.ts"],
    "testTimeout": 20000,
    "globalTeardown": "./globalTeardown.ts",
    "reporters": [
        "default",
        [
            "jest-html-reporters",
            {
                "publicPath": "./report",
                "filename": "report.html",
                "customInfos": "JEST_HTML_REPORTERS_CUSTOM_INFOS"
            }
        ]
    ]
}

With this, I am getting an json parsing error for string. If I provide an array of string, it returns undefined. I setup env variable but it seems it is not reading from ENV
can someone guide to the process of doing it?
